# Unique ways to represent a number

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, binomial-theorem

I know two ways to represent a number,

1. Muliplication of primes

Any number can be represented uniquely as a product of prime numbers

2. Binomial Representation

Any number can be represented uniquely as a sum of powers of 2

Are there any other interesting ways to uniquely represent a number?

Comment: are you talking about natural numbers?  decimal notation?

Comment: [Fibonacci representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) is good.

Comment: Natural numbers only

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system is cool

Comment: Maybe people could add other suggestions to the CW answer below.

Comment: Since you refer to binomial representation, which in effect is binary representation and employs two digital symbols ($0,1$), I don't see why representation in any base $n$ employing $n$ digital symbols does not qualify as a unique representation, i.e., the sum of some number of powers of the base in which the number is being represented.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQZmZRE0cQY&app=desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Fibonacci representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) (sum of Fibonacci numbers with no repeats or consecutive Fibonacci numbers).

The [factorial system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system) eg $463=3\cdot5!+4\cdot4!+1\cdot3!+0\cdot2!+1\cdot1!$ where the "digit" corresponding to $n!$ can be any of $0,1,\dots,n$.

[Balanced ternary](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_bt.htm) ie ternary using the digits $\bar{1},0,1$, where $\bar{1}$ represents $-1$.